# How to dry run a request in a browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, safari, http-post

I am clicking a button in chrome upon which a POST request is sent to the server.
I want to capture this request without actually sending the request to the server something like a dry run.

Because if I let this request succeed and I replay it, I know the backend will throw the exception. Another reason is that the front end is dynamically setting a lot of fields every time.

If I can do this, I can easily copy the request body and play around with it.

Can we do something like blocking a request ?
Does chrome or any browser support it or is there an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Network tab in Chrome. On top, you can see a dropdown with Online selected by default. Select offline.

[image: Network tab]

Now send the request. You will see the request fails as if the network is disconnected.

[image: Request failing after switching to offline mode]